# $httpProvider.interceptors works after page load

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to handle http errors globally in angularjs code.

Below is my code in ".config" section:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
            return {
                'responseError': function (rejection) {
                    var status = rejection.status;
                    var config = rejection.config;
                    var method = config.method;
                    var url = config.url;

                    if (status == 401) {
                        $location.path('/401');
                    } else {
                        $rootScope.error = method + " on " + url + " failed with status " + status;
                    }

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        });
```

It redirects user to "401" page but after rendering the current request.

How can I make it work before actual request.

**Update:**
Here is my updated code after mJunaidSalaat's response:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
            return {
                'request': function(config) {
              //do any  thing you want to test here.
              //if (config.method === 'GET' || userSession.isAuth()) {
              // the request looks good, so return the config
              console.log("Before Request: "+ config);
              return config;
              //}

              // bad request, so reject
              //return $q.reject(config);

            },
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                console.log("After Request: ");
                var status = rejection.status;
                var config = rejection.config;
                var method = config.method;
                var url = config.url;

                if (status == 401) {
                    $location.path('/401');
                } else {
                    $rootScope.error = method + " on " + url + " failed with status " + status;
                }

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to intercept the call before making the request.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
        return {
           // run this function before making requests
           'request': function(config) {
              //do any  thing you want to test here.
              //if (config.method === 'GET' || userSession.isAuth()) {
              // the request looks good, so return the config
              console.log("Before Request: "+ config);
              return config;
              //}

              // bad request, so reject
              //return $q.reject(config);

            }
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                var status = rejection.status;
                var config = rejection.config;
                var method = config.method;
                var url = config.url;

                if (status == 401) {
                    $location.path('/401');
                } else {
                    $rootScope.error = method + " on " + url + " failed with status " + status;
                }

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx for your response, but where should I add this in my above code?

Comment: I've added this with your code. Please see the updated answer

Comment: No It should work. Please try the updated code. I've added a `console.log` to show that the code is getting there before the request.

Comment: I am sorry. . .but it still first load actual page then redirects to 401.

Comment: have you check your console?

Comment: I don't get it. I've implemented this in my code and it works perfectly. You must be doing some thing wrong I think.

Comment: Yes it prints "Before request" first then "After request" but some how actual page is loading first.

Comment: Yes that `before request` is printed from the code you've written from above. That means you could do anything before making your call there.

Comment: If you want to cancel that request don't return the config. comment that line of code `//return config`